# log4j.PatternLayout: Why /MMM/ produce both /Mrz/ and /Mär/ in Germany?

Tags: java, date, logging, log4j

We use `org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout` in Log4j (still using `log4j-1.2.13.jar` everywhere). We are in Germany, using German Windows 2008 Server R2 on multiple servers. And we use the same pattern for the dates:

```
[%d{dd/MMM/yyyy:HH:mm:ss}]
```

All servers produced /Mrz/ today, except one that spits out /Mär/.

All servers have the same log4j Jar, the same log4j configuration patterns, the same values in the Windows "Clock/Region und Sprache(Region and language)/Formate" tab, and same time-zone too (printed out as MEZ).

We have different Java processes running on the same server, each with it's own log4j config file, and all produce the same /Mär/ on that one server, so I suspect it's a Windows configuration setting.

What could be causing this difference in the month's textual representation?

Comment: Do you have distinct JRE ? There may be bugs like this one : https://bugs.openjdk.java.net/browse/JDK-8075173

Comment: It might be the [java local arguments](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E23507_01/Platform.20073/ATGProgGuide/html/s1809settingthejavavirtualmachineloca01.html).

Comment: Obviously you have different JDKs with different resources. JDK takes its i18n-data from CLDR. And in that repository, the change from "Mrz" to "Mär" was done in either version v16 or v17 a long time ago. We also have to note that the JDK is often pretty far behind CLDR (in terms of actuality).

Comment: We very recently updated form Java 7 to Java 8 runtime, and so all servers got updated at the same time with the same JDK: (build 1.8.0_45-b15). We don't let Java update itself automatically on servers. Also, I checked the "java local arguments", and they are the same on the command line. I still have to check if they are set programatically, since the "app versions" differ.

Comment: We do not set "user.language" or "user.region" programatically, but we call Locale.setDefault(Locale.GERMANY) in the main everywhere (apparently, since 2001(!), according to a code comment) so it's not that either.

Comment: I've copied the deployment directory from the "deviant server" to my workstation, including code, configuration and data. On my PC it produces /Mrz/ (expected value), so IMHO it must be something to do with the Windows settings, since the same deployment gives different results on different computers.